# Should there be a special flag for a question that is in need of ESL grammatical review?

Tags: discussion, languages

I see many posts that are a bit/severely down-voted because the post is not entirely clear due to a linguistics problem(s). Not like the user didn't demonstrate proper attempts at writing code to solve his problem: just "not clear; try to make the post better."

But I feel that is not entirely on the OP. Would there be some way to tag a post on the "our" English-language site as "ESL: need a bit of help rewording the question"? and have a group of mods that try to do so, when the question wasn't in fact lazily constructed, but just needs a hand with grammar, syntax, and vocabulary?

I searched on meta, but was not able to find such a thing.

Comment: I think the better - and faster - thing to do is to edit the post for clarity.  I, personally, would rather edit the question and get the problem fixed rather than create a process about what to do when a question like that appears.

Comment: Why seven downvotes without a single explanation? Does downvoting work differently here than on stackoverflow?

Comment: @thomas On Meta, downvotes can mean disagreement with your proposal.

Answer (score 4):

We can fix things, but the asker should make a best effort to write the text properly in the first place.  There are numerous online spelling and grammar checkers out there such as http://spellcheckplus.com (or even pasting it into a word processor and running a grammar check on it).

The community *can* fix problems, but it is important that the asker makes a best effort to write the best possible question they can.  This involves properly formatting the code and and using existing tools to write the question (or answer) in a clear and comprehensible way.  Asking the community to fix all of this for you (how many times do you see a super large 'include' in the middle of the question?) shows laziness on the part of the asker and a disrespect of the community to even *attempt* to format and word the post in accordance with the norms.

Answer (score -1):

I doubt that you'll find a ton of support for this, but I actually think the idea has merit. I certainly see a lot of questions where the posters obviously struggle with writing an easy to read post, based on a language barrier. And I think it's very unfortunate if their questions get downvoted/closed in response, even though they might have technical merit, and the OP in fact put in a lot more effort than most native English speakers put into their questions.

The challenge is of course finding a viable way how this could be implemented. Getting multiple sites involved sounds complex. One possible low-tech approach that immediately comes to mind:

1. Give the OP an opportunity to add a special tag to their questions, which I will call [english-help-wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/english-help-wanted) for now (probably less verbose in reality).
2. People willing to help out with editing these posts can easily find them by searching for posts with the [english-help-wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/english-help-wanted) tag.
3. As part of their language cleanup edit, the editor removes the [english-help-wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/english-help-wanted) tag.

Of course the posts would need to be clear enough for volunteer editors to understand. But I believe many of the posts that look kind of rough today can be interpreted well enough, once you take the effort to dig into them, and have some talent to read between the lines.

Then the most critical point is that there actually are people willing to edit the posts. They definitely don't need to be moderators. The only question is if users with full edit privileges (2k rep) would take on this work, or if it would also be open for users who need to get their work approved in the review queue.

I think there might be enough volunteers to handle this. I've seen various people posting here on Meta expressing how much they enjoy editing, and partly end up fighting people who don't like to see their posts edited. This would give them an easy way to find posts that need editing, from posters who very much appreciate their help.

Comment: The 2K rep minimum could be waived for questions that are marked `english-help-wanted`. At the price of a bit of complexity, you could even restrict sub-2K editors from changing the code parts of a question. But one should check if posters with poor English skills even understand Markdown.